# Triple pendulum simulation is out of control

Tags: angular, typescript, animation, math, html5-canvas

I'm trying to make a triple pendulum in html5's canvas element whilst using angular.

```
interface Bob {
  mass: number;
  length: number;
  angle: number;
  velocity: number;
  x: number;
  y: number;
  acc: number
}

export class PendulumBobs {
  private bob1: Bob = {
    mass: 10,
    length: 0,
    angle: Math.PI / 2,
    velocity: 0,
    x: 0, y: 0,
    acc: 0
  }

  private bob2: Bob = {
    mass: 10,
    length: 0,
    angle: Math.PI / 2,
    velocity: 10,
    x: 0, y: 0,
    acc: 0
  }

  private bob3: Bob = {
    mass: 10,
    length: 0,
    angle: Math.PI / 2,
    velocity: 0,
    x: 0, y: 0,
    acc: 0
  }

  public radius: number = 10;
  public color: string = 'black';

  private canvas!: any;
  private c!: CanvasRenderingContext2D;

  private gravity: number = 1;

  length = {
    bob1: 0, bob2: 0, bob3: 0
  }
  constructor(
    canvas: HTMLCanvasElement, 
    color: string, 
    radius: number, 
    length1: number, length2: number, length3: number
  ) {

    this.canvas = canvas;
    this.c = this.canvas.getContext('2d');

    this.length.bob1 = length1;
    this.length.bob2 = length2;
    this.length.bob3 = length3;

    this.bob1.length = this.length.bob1;
    this.bob2.length = this.length.bob2;
    this.bob3.length = this.length.bob3;

    this.radius = radius
  };

  line(x1: number, y1: number, x2: number, y2: number, color: string) {
    this.c.beginPath();
    this.c.moveTo(x1, y1);
    this.c.lineTo(x2, y2);
    this.c.strokeStyle = color;
    this.c.stroke();
  } 

  bob(xCoord: number, yCoord: number, radius: number, color: string) {
    this.c.beginPath();
    this.c.arc(xCoord, yCoord, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    this.c.fillStyle = color;
    this.c.fill();
    this.c.closePath();
  }

  draw() {
    //drawing the pendulum
    this.line(this.c.canvas.width/2, 0, this.bob1.x, this.bob1.y, this.color);
    this.bob(this.bob1.x, this.bob1.y, this.radius, this.color);
    //first string and bob ^
    this.line(this.bob1.x, this.bob1.y, this.bob2.x, this.bob2.y, this.color);
    this.bob(this.bob2.x, this.bob2.y, this.radius, this.color);
    //second string and bob ^^
    this.line(this.bob2.x, this.bob2.y, this.bob3.x, this.bob3.y, this.color);
    this.bob(this.bob3.x, this.bob3.y, this.radius, this.color);
    //third string and bob ^^
  }

  update() {
    let formula1 = {
      part1: this.gravity*this.bob1.length*(this.bob1.mass*this.sin(this.bob1.angle)+this.bob2.mass*this.sin(this.bob1.angle)+this.bob3.mass*this.sin(this.bob1.angle))+this.bob2.mass*this.bob1.length*this.bob2.length*this.sin(this.bob1.angle-this.bob2.angle)*this.bob1.velocity*this.bob2.velocity,
      part2: this.bob3.mass*this.bob1.length*this.bob3.length*this.sin(this.bob1.angle-this.bob3.angle)*this.bob1.velocity*this.bob3.velocity+this.bob3.mass*this.bob1.length*this.bob2.length*this.sin(this.bob1.angle-this.bob2.angle)*this.bob1.velocity*this.bob2.velocity+this.bob1.length**2*this.bob1.acc*(this.bob1.mass+this.bob2.mass+this.bob3.mass),
      part3: this.bob2.mass*this.bob1.length*this.bob2.length*this.sin(this.bob2.angle-this.bob1.angle)*(this.bob1.velocity-this.bob2.velocity)*this.bob2.velocity+this.cos(this.bob1.angle-this.bob2.angle)*this.bob2.acc,
      part4: this.bob3.mass*this.bob1.length*this.bob2.length*this.sin(this.bob2.angle-this.bob1.angle)*(this.bob1.velocity-this.bob2.velocity)*this.bob2.velocity+this.cos(this.bob1.angle-this.bob2.angle)*this.bob2.acc,
      part5: this.bob3.mass*this.bob1.length*this.bob3.length*this.sin(this.bob3.angle-this.bob1.angle)*(this.bob1.velocity-this.bob3.velocity)*this.bob3.velocity+this.cos(this.bob1.angle-this.bob3.angle)*this.bob3.acc
    }
    this.bob1.angle = formula1.part1 + formula1.part2 + formula1.part3 + formula1.part4 + formula1.part5;

    let formula2 = {
      part1: this.gravity*this.bob2.length*(this.bob2.mass*this.sin(this.bob2.angle)+this.bob3.mass*this.sin(this.bob2.angle))+this.bob1.velocity*this.bob2.velocity*this.bob1.length*this.bob2.length*this.sin(this.bob2.angle-this.bob1.angle)*(this.bob2.mass+this.bob3.mass),
      part2: this.bob3.mass*this.bob2.length*this.bob3.length*this.sin(this.bob2.angle-this.bob3.angle)*this.bob2.velocity*this.bob3.velocity+this.bob2.length**2*this.bob2.acc*(this.bob2.mass+this.bob3.mass),
      part3: (this.bob2.mass+this.bob3.mass)*this.bob1.length*this.bob2.length*(this.sin(this.bob2.velocity-this.bob1.velocity)*( this.bob1.velocity-this.bob2.velocity)*this.bob1.velocity+this.cos(this.bob2.velocity-this.bob1.velocity)*this.bob1.acc),
      part4: this.bob3.mass*this.bob2.length*this.bob3.length*(this.sin(this.bob3.angle-this.bob2.angle)*( this.bob2.velocity-this.bob3.velocity)*this.bob3.velocity+this.cos(this.bob2.angle-this.bob3.angle)*this.bob3.acc)
    }
    this.bob2.angle = formula2.part1 + formula2.part2 + formula2.part3 + formula2.part4;

    let formula3 = {
      part1: this.bob3.mass*this.gravity*this.bob3.length*this.sin(this.bob3.angle)-this.bob3.mass*this.bob1.length*this.bob3.length*this.sin(this.bob2.angle-this.bob3.angle)*this.bob2.velocity*this.bob3.velocity-this.bob3.mass*this.bob1.length*this.bob3.length*this.sin(this.bob1.angle-this.bob3.angle)*this.bob1.velocity*this.bob3.velocity,
      part2: this.bob3.mass*this.bob1.length*this.bob3.length*(this.sin(this.bob3.angle-this.bob1.angle)*(this.bob1.velocity-this.bob3.velocity)*this.bob1.velocity+this.cos(this.bob1.angle-this.bob3.angle)*this.bob1.acc),
      part3: this.bob3.mass*this.bob1.length*this.bob3.length*(this.sin(this.bob3.angle-this.bob2.angle)*(this.bob2.velocity-this.bob3.velocity)*this.bob2.velocity+this.cos(this.bob2.angle-this.bob3.angle)*this.bob2.acc)+this.bob3.mass*this.bob2.length**2*this.bob3.acc
    }
    this.bob3.angle = formula3.part1 + formula3.part2 + formula3.part3;

    this.bob1.x =  this.canvas.width/2 + this.bob1.length * Math.sin(this.bob1.angle);
    this.bob1.y = this.bob1.length * Math.cos(this.bob1.angle);

    this.bob2.x = this.bob1.x + this.bob2.length * Math.sin(this.bob2.angle);
    this.bob2.y = this.bob1.y + this.bob2.length * Math.cos(this.bob2.angle);

    this.bob3.x = this.bob2.x + this.bob3.length * Math.sin(this.bob3.angle);
    this.bob3.y = this.bob2.y + this.bob3.length * Math.cos(this.bob3.angle);
    this.draw()
  }

  sin(x: number) {
    return Math.sin(x)
  }

  cos(x: number) {
   return Math.cos(x)
  } 
}
```

The above code block is my triple pendulum class. For each of their angle I use the three formulas from https://www.researchgate.net/publication/336868500_Equations_of_Motion_Formulation_of_a_Pendulum_Containing_N-point_Masses

The formulas can be seen on the 5th and 6th pages.

When I finally completed the class I use it in my triple-pendulum component and initialize it

```
 @ViewChild('canvas', {static: false}) canvas!: ElementRef;
 private c!: CanvasRenderingContext2D;
 triplePendulum!: PendulumBobs;

 constructor() { };

 ngAfterViewInit(): void {
   this.c = this.canvas.nativeElement.getContext('2d');
   this.c.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
   this.c.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
   this.c.translate(0, 300)

   this.triplePendulum = new PendulumBobs(
     this.canvas.nativeElement,
     'black',
     10,
     this.canvas.nativeElement.width / this.canvas.nativeElement.height * 60,
     this.canvas.nativeElement.width / this.canvas.nativeElement.height * 60,
     this.canvas.nativeElement.width / this.canvas.nativeElement.height * 60,
   );
   this.animate()
 }

 animate() {
   requestAnimationFrame(() => this.animate());
   this.c.clearRect(0, -this.c.canvas.height, this.c.canvas.width, this.c.canvas.height * 2);
   this.triplePendulum.update();
 }
```

But when I run my project the triple pendulum is all erratic and doesn't look like a proper pendulum at all. I'm pretty sure the issue is in some variable of the bob objects in the pendulum class that I created, but I don't know what it is.

[image]

The above gif is just a representation of how unnatural and erratic the simulation is.
Please suggest a possible solution to this problem

Comment: Try using a smaller gravity constant. Also consider writing some subroutines for your one-liners that I can't even fit in this comment. How can you be sure they don't contain logical errors?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts sure I will shorten and simplify them for easier understanding

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I have organized the code, are you able to find any bugs or logical errors ?

Comment: Rithish, I think you've made a good start, but it seem unlikely anyone will be able to see the error in your code. Some ideas to help you make progress. (1) Try using a smaller time step. Try 1/10 or 1/100 of whatever it is now. That should make the motion slower and smoother. (2) Try printing out the x and y coordinates at each step. I forget exactly what the solution is, but it should look more or less like superimposed waves. (3) The triple pendulum is interesting but it is actually a hard problem. Try a simple pendulum first. Good luck and have fun.